# Are add-link-only tag wiki edits allowed?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, error-message

I've recently tried to edit the [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces) tag wiki by adding the link to official forum to the link section.

I've got a message

> An error occured submiting the post.

It is not very explanatory, but is it a way to say that adding a link is not a good tag wiki edit, or it's actually an error in SO engine?

Comment: I would have guessed this was a problem with your connection or some other completely unrelated SE issue. Did you try resubmitting the suggestion and did it work?

Comment: Oh yes, including other computer with a few-hours distance.